# What is the reasoning for higher pH values in this scene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

In this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228478528_Low_Boiling_Point_Organic_Amine-Catalyzed_Transesterification_for_Biodiesel_Production) regarding low-boiling point amine-catalyzed biodiesel transesterification reactions, it is stated that,

> "From Table 1, we can also see that, for the isomers, the
>   branched amines always showed higher yields of methyl acetate
>   than the normal amines. For example, the yields of methyl
>   acetate for n-dipropylamine, n-butylamine, and n-propylamine
>   were 25.3%, 46.1%, and 48.2%, respectively, while those for
>   diisopropylamine, tert-butylamine, and isopropylamine were
>   42.1%, 49.6%, and 50.7%, respectively. This was probably due
>   to the high pH values of the branched amines than the normal
>   amines."

Why is this the case? Why do high pH values correlate to higher yields? Does the geometry (branched or linear) of the amine play a role in this?

Answer (score 1):

Branched amines are more basic than their linear counterparts because [inductive effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect) of alkanes places more electron density in the adjacent carbon atom. The higher the electron density near/at the amine group, the higher its pH will be.

Comment: Also, steric factors also make the amine more planar, so the lone pair orbital is going to have less mixing/stabilization from the orbitals of the other substituents.